# How to check if current user has finished the survey questions?

Tags: survey

I created a custom webpart with inside it the pageviewer webpart. How can I check programmatically if the current user has finished the survey questions?

Note
It is also possible to save the survey questions without finished it.

Comment: Have you tried with clientside javascript?

Comment: no, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by my self:

```
private bool IsSurveyCompleted()
        {
            bool result = false;

            // check if the url is not null or empty
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_SurveyListUrl))
            {
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
                        {
                            // get completed survey list item for current user
                            SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
                            var userId = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID;
                            q.Query = string.Format("<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Completed\" /><Value Type=\"Boolean\">1</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Author\" LookupId=\"True\"/><Value Type=\"User\">{0}</Value></Eq></And></Where>", userId);

                            SPList list = web.GetList(_SurveyListUrl); 

                            if (list != null)
                            {
                                SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(q);

                                if (items.Count > 0)
                                {
                                 result = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

            return result;

        }
```