# how to check if user has already responded to a survey using JSOM/Javascript

Tags: 2013, jsom, survey, survey-list

How can I check if the current user has already responded using JSOM/Javascript or jquery?

I checked this [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144672)  but it is not in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a (hidden) ListView WebPart to the page displaying all Survey Items filtered on [ME]

If the View is empty the user hasn't responded yet.

Takes Client Side Rendering with 3 lines of JavaScript in the OnPostRender method